# Merging two scrolled and zoomed images in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to create a functionallity like in PicFrame or any other application for creating photo collage in one frame.

I've created two scroll views and two image views in these scroll views for scrolling and zooming the images. It works well.

Then I need to create one square image of the two rectangular images.

```
var firstImage = UIImage(named: leftImagePath)
var secondImage = UIImage(named: rightImagePath)

var size = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1080)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

let leftImageAreaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width / 2, height: size.height)
firstImage!.drawInRect(leftImageAreaSize)

let rightImageAreaSize = CGRect(x: size.width / 2 + 1 , y: 0, width: size.width / 2, height: size.height)
secondImage!.drawInRect(rightImageAreaSize)

var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This code works well, but I need to implement the scroll and zoom values, crop and scale the images using these values before creating one square image.

Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I make PicFrame so I suppose I have some experience here. Although this isn't what I do, and I haven't tried it myself, if you just want a quick image of what you see you could use [drawViewHierarchyInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) and capture the screen area.

Otherwise what you want to do is get the CGPoint contentOffset and the CGSize bounds.size from the UIScrollView. Then you modify these by the UIScrollView zoomScale. Make sure your contentSize is the size of the image so that a zoomScale of 1.0 would have the width and height of the original image.

From this you should be able to make a CGRect which is the x, y, width, height of what is visible in your scroll view but translated to the size of the image. Crop the image to this size and then draw it into your final graphics context with your desired CGRect.

Comment: Would you please provide me with a example of code? I'm interesting in the second method.